# SVG path extrude seems to leave open objects

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I want to visualize constructing (sliding & press fitting) a few multiplex panels into a table or stool. The shapes of these panels can be provided in SVG or DXF.
The svg is [here online](http://www.stretchsketch.com/barkruk.svg). I tried to extrude that shape using [this tutorial](http://spolearninglab.com/curriculum/software/3d_modeling/blender/blender_02.html) (skipping the inkscape part).

I only seem to be able to extrude the borderlines of the elements not the surface of the element, also the holes don't look like holes. I made sure that the SVG-paths are closed, but still not the desired output.

[image: imported svg curves in blender]

Comment: PS you aren't using 2.77b, there is only 2.77a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sert the curves to be **2D** shape and Fill to **Both**:

[image]